# server side c# method is not calling from ajax - asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am trying to call a c# method using ajax as below.

```
<a href="#divrecentQ" id="linkdivrecentQ" onclick="lnkClick();" aria-controls="divrecentQ" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Click here</a>
```

Here is the method in JS

```
    function lnkClick() {
        alert("called");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/amain.aspx/LoadImages',
            data: {},
            success: function () {
                alert(1);
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
        alert("cal");
    }
```

Server side:

```
    public static void LoadImages()
    {
       
        log.Debug("LoadImages is called");
       
    }
```

Server side method is not getting called.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: don't you need to specify `[WebMethod]` on the method?

Comment: made the changes. still not working

Comment: error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } try this code inside ajax to check any error

Comment: Have look my answer of previous question [Stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36589613/4611027)   make sure function is call after initialize of jQuery

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized. If you have routeConfig file under App_Start, you need to change the AutoRedirectMode

Comment: @rech. I dont have App_start folder in web app !!

Comment: Add error function for ajax so you will see the error message in your console.

Comment: @rach. yes it worked. but now it is executing everytime page loads.. I want it to be called only on link click. any suggestion?

Comment: Update your code please

Comment: @rach. It worked. thanks a lot. :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 
"contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"," in jquery called the server side method.

Thanks everyone for help. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should define the method static and wrap it with `[WebMethod]` attribute.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void LoadImages()
{

    Label1.Text = "hi therre";
    Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
    log.Debug("LoadImages is called");

}
```

Comment: apology. did undo.

Comment: @DKR put breaking point in load images check if it is going in the method. IF it is not check your console for errors from javascript side

Comment: it is not going in method. How do I start console to chek js errors?

Comment: @DKR in chrome right mouse click-> Inspect-> Second tab -> Console. Clear the console try to execute your ajax check for errors.

Comment: It gives error as "undefined". but not about which symbol

Comment: There is no error for js, undefined is something else... dunno whats causing this. anyway thanks for your time. appreciate it